# Error in java class path in ant build Oxygen Dita-Ot

Tags: java, xml, ant, build, dita

Hi I am getting this error even after including jdk path location. Its showing

```
Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\tools.jar
```

the cmd code generated this

```
C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 17\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x>ant -f integrator.xml
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 17\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\integrator.xml

strict:

integrate:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 17\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\integrator.xml:66: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 17\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\integrator.xml:44: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.dita.dost.platform.Integrator.writePlugins(Integrator.java:514)
        at org.dita.dost.platform.Integrator.integrate(Integrator.java:207)
        at org.dita.dost.platform.Integrator.execute(Integrator.java:200)
        at org.dita.dost.platform.IntegratorTask.execute(IntegratorTask.java:40)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net/sf/saxon/TransformerFactoryImpl
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 38 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Is there is something wrong with the class path or with the integrator xml file ? I had followed the steps given in oxygen dita-ot website and book .

I think the problem is in this section

```
 C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 17\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\integrator.xml:66: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 17\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\integrator.xml:44: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
```

And My line number(44,66) of integrator says this , to which i am unable to understand.

```
44  <integrate ditadir="${dita.dir}" strict="${strict}"/>

65<target name="strict" description="Run integration in strict mode">
  66  <antcall target="integrate">
    67  <param name="strict" value="true"/>
    68</antcall>
  69</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

tools.jar only exists in JDK package rather than in JRE package. You need to download JDK8 package and install it, then link the system properties(JAVA_HOME and PATH) to new JDK installation directory path.

[JDK8 download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

After all, rerun your command.

Comment: Thank You , but I have already downloaded the latest jdk version. And what do you exactly mean by JAVA_HOME ? path I know.

Comment: JAVA_HOME means the JDK installation directory, on my computer it's "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60", and add "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;" to the head of PATH value. Then try it again:)

Comment: Thank You , I got it already and my file is building successfuly

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run integrator.xml from the command-line and the error message says that Saxon is not in the classpath.

Usually oXygen user invoke oXygen by administrator privileges and select "Document" - "Transformation" - "Configure Transformation Scenario" - "Run DITA OT Integrator".

[image: Transformation Scenario]

```
Executing:
"c:\program files\oxygen xml editor 18.1\jre/bin/java" -Xmx256m -classpath "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\tools\ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar" "-Dant.home=C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\tools\ant" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\ant-apache-resolver-1.9.4.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\ant-launcher.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\ant.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\dost-configuration.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\dost-patches.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\dost.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\guava-19.0.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\jsearch.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar" -lib "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\xml-resolver-1.2.jar" -f "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks/dita/DITA-OT2.x/integrator.xml" "-Dstrict=true" "-Dwebhelp.trial.license=no"

Buildfile: C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\integrator.xml

strict:

integrate:
      [jar] Building jar: C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 18.1\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x\lib\dost-configuration.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 9 seconds

The process finished with exit code: 0
```

This method will solve your problem.

Comment: Sure Sir , I will try this then let u know

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you are using the 2.x version of the DITA OT. But you are using the integrator command for an older OT version.

You can use Oxygen to run the integrator, but if you want to run it from the command line, do this:

1. Open a command window as Administrator: Press Start, type cmd, when cmd.exe appears, right click it and choose "Run as administrator".
2. Navigate to the Oxygen 2.x DITA OT:

   C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 17\frameworks\dita\DITA-OT2.x
3. Enter this command:

   bin\dita -install

If it returns to the prompt with no errors, you should be good to go.

By the way, the tools.jar error is usually not something to worry about.

Comment: You're welcome, can you click up on the arrow so I get my brownie points?